# Display:none option in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I do permissions (rolls) system!
For starters, I made 3 permissions
-newbie
-member
-admin

In PHP code I put 3 checks on what will happen if I have one of these permissions.
Everything works normally and properly!
My navigation bar consists of 5  tags:

```
<a href="home.php">Home </a>
<a href="pm.php">Private Message</a>
<a href="accountoptions.php">account options</a>
<a href="abtd.php">About the developer</a>
<a href="supp.php">Support</a>
```

I added another `<a>` tag by name `"admin.php"` and added `style = "display: none"`

```
<a href="admin.php" id='adminpanel' style="display:none">Admin</a>
```

and when admin logs in to create this `<a>` tag named `"admin.php"`

I put in a login check for admin if admin is to show him this `<a>` tag `"admin.php"`

put this part of the code in check myself

```
echo '<style>#adminpanel { display:block;}</style>';
```

However, nothing is happening, please show me where I am wrong.

Comment: Try reversing the logic. It will start working :)

Comment: @PavelJanicek Who do you think I change the logic for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple logic:

```
<?php if($is_admin_login){ ?>
    <a href="admin.php" id='adminpanel'>Admin</a>
    <?php }else if($is_member_login){?>
    <a href="member.php" id='member'>Member</a>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: how you define these variables

Comment: $is_admin_login -> Check if Admin is login, Add your code, how you are checking that admin is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable $isAdmin = true|false (or similar) then it is simple

```
echo '<a href="admin.php" id="adminpanel"';
if ($isAdmin) echo ' style="display:none"';
echo '>Admin</a>';
```